# Can not open file using open_file package flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to open a file using the open file flutter package, the file exists but it is not opening.

I dont get any errors as well. A snippet is posted.

```
var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

            File myFile = File('${dir.path}/$classCode/$fileName.$fileType');

            if (myFile.existsSync()) {

              print('file present');

            }
            print(myFile.toString());

            myFile.exists().then((value) async {

              print('hello');

              return await OpenFile.open('${myFile.toString()}');

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `return await OpenFile.open('${myFile.toString()}');`

to `return await OpenFile.open('${myFile.path.toString()}');`